# How to add a button to the last cell of a horizontal collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that populates its cells with images from the server. Now after a user has scrolled horizontally to the last cell I want to display a button that will allow the user to click on and perform and action. I have tried appending a button to the last end of the configure function but that didn't work

```
private let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 170, height: 170)
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(DashboardCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: DashboardCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        return collectionView
    }()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: DashboardCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? DashboardCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        cell.configure(with: recons[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recons.count
    }

class DashboardCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier = "DashboardCollectionViewCell"
    private let posterImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        return image
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.addSubview(posterImage)
        posterImage.addSubview(btnRate)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            posterImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            posterImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
posterImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            posterImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170),
posterImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            posterImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170),
            btnRate.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: posterImage.centerYAnchor),
            btnRate.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: posterImage.centerXAnchor),
            btnRate.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            btnRate.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            
        ])
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        posterImage.image = nil
    }
    
    public func configure(with model: Item){
        //will load images in the cell
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display a button "on top of the poster image in the last cell"? Or, do you want to display a button "to the right of the last cell"?

Comment: In other words... Do you want "A" or "B": https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zXnP.png

Comment: @DonMag I want B

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ***last cell*** to have only a button, create another cell class such as:

```
class DashboardLastCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier = "DashboardLastCell"

    // no poster image
    // just a button in the cell
    
}
```

then, in `viewDidLoad`, register that cell also:

```
    collectionView.register(DashboardCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: DashboardCollectionViewCell.identifier)
    collectionView.register(DashboardLastCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: DashboardLastCell.identifier)
```

for `numberOfItemsInSection`, return your array count PLUS 1:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recons.count + 1
}
```

and, in `cellForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    if indexPath.item == recons.count {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: DashboardLastCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! DashboardLastCell
        // this cell has only a button - do what you want with it
        return cell
    }

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: DashboardCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! DashboardCollectionViewCell
    cell.configure(with: recons[indexPath.row])
    return cell
    
}
```

now your collection view can look like this:

[image]