# UIButton doesn't respond to clicks inside UICollectionViewCell which is also inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UIButton which is inside a UICollectionViewCell which is also inside a UITableViewCell. My UICollectionViewCell displays images and at the very end of the last image cell it displays the UIButton which users can click on to perform an action. I have added a target to my button but it doesn't work

```
private let dashboardFeedTable: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        table.register(DashboardCollectionViewTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: DashboardCollectionViewTableViewCell.identifier)
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        table.backgroundColor = .white
        return table
    }()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DashboardCollectionViewTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? DashboardCollectionViewTableViewCell else {
                return UITableViewCell()
                }
            cell.configure(with: objItems)
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
    }

class DashboardCollectionViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "DashboardCollectionViewTableViewCell"
    var delegate : CellDelegate?
    private var recons: [Item] = [Item]()
    
    private let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 170, height: 170)
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(DashboardCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: DashboardCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.layer.borderWidth = 0
        collectionView.layer.borderColor = .none
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        collectionView.frame = contentView.bounds
    }
    
    public func configure(with recons: [Item]){
        self.recons = recons
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: DashboardCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? DashboardCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        cell.configure(with: recons[indexPath.row])
        
        cell.btnRateMore.isHidden = indexPath.row != recons.count - 1
        cell.btnRateMore.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showMore(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

class DashboardCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "DashboardCollectionViewCell"
    
    private let posterImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
//        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        return image
    }()
    
    lazy var btnRateMore: ButtonRating = {
        let btn = ButtonRating()
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btn.layer.borderWidth = 1
        btn.setTitleColor(.collectivlyColour, for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: String.circularStdBold, size: 14)
        btn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        btn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        btn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.collectivlyColour.cgColor
        return btn
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        contentView.addSubview(posterImage)
        contentView.addSubview(btnRateMore)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            posterImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            posterImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
posterImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
posterImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170),
posterImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
posterImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170),
btnRateMore.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: posterImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 30),
            btnRateMore.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),        btnRateMore.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170),    btnRateMore.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170),    
        ])
        btnRateMore.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showMore(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        posterImage.image = nil
    }
    
    public func configure(with model: Item){
        let url = model.packShot.thumbnail
        guard let url = URL(string: url ?? "") else {
            return
        }
        
        posterImage.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholder"))
    }
    
    
    @objc func showMore(_ sender: UIButton){
        print("show more")
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: While running your app, use Xcode's Debug view hierarchy feature and verify that the button isn't being clipped by the collection view cell or the table view cell.

Comment: You are placing the button **outside the bounds** of the cell. This is similar to your problem with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75682319/how-to-add-a-button-to-the-last-cell-of-a-horizontal-collection-view ...  Did you look at my answer to that question? It would solve both of your problems.

Comment: @DonMag I tried your solution and it also didn't work. But I have noticed I have to open another question because of how my collectionView is rendered. So basically I have a tableview which has a collectionView. And the collectionView has these cells with posterImage and the LastButton. So I'm thinking using a delegate will solve the button click because I'm using delegate to access click event on the posterImage.

Comment: @KwameB - *"it also didn't work"* doesn't tell us much. **What** didn't work? Does the button respond visually, but nothing happens? What code did you write to *make* something happen?